# Copy and Paste to next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies a range, pastes the range a certain number of times based on another cells value into Sheet2, however it's overlapping each set in the loop rather than pasting into the next open cell in Column A...

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim numberOfCopies As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long

'## Define a range to represent ALL the data
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").End(xlDown))
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'## Iterate each row in that data range
For Each r In rng.Rows
    '## Get the number of copies specified in column 14 ("N")
    numberOfCopies = r.Cells(1, 35).Value

    '## If that number > 1 then make copies on a new sheet
    If numberOfCopies > 1 Then
        '## Add a new sheet
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")


            '## copy the row and paste repeatedly in this loop

            For n = 1 To numberOfCopies
                r.Copy .Range("A" & n)
            Next
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: `n` always starts again at 1 in each iteration of your `r` loop. Use your `lastrow` variable.

Comment: changed it to: r.Copy .Range("A" & lastrow) and still overwrites each other.

Comment: Because you haven't updated `lastrow` after entering the loop.  BTW your comment has column 14 but your code has 35.

Comment: Oh thanks! Didn't catch that in my comment, ty. I'm sorry what do you mean by updating lastrow. How would you change the code? I'm a total novice at some of this stuff, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested it so let me know if it doesn't work properly.

I've added a few comments.

I think you can dispense with the inner loop by using `Resize`.

```
Sub x()

Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim numberOfCopies As Long 'use long rather than integer
Dim n As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

'## Define a range to represent ALL the data
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("A3", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'work up from the bottom rather than top down
End With
'## Iterate each row in that data range
For Each r In rng.Rows
    '## Get the number of copies specified in column 14 ("N")
    numberOfCopies = r.Cells(1, 35).Value
    '## If that number > 1 then make copies on a new sheet
    If numberOfCopies > 1 Then
        '## Add a new sheet
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            '## copy the row and paste repeatedly in this loop
            lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'want the row below last used one
            r.Copy .Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(numberOfCopies)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like it's very close, It gives an error on the line with "r.Copy .Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(n)"  Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I've changed that line above.

Comment: Where would I change the code to paste only the values rather than formatting and values?

Comment: You could replace the Copy line with `.Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(numberOfCopies,3).value=r.value`.

Comment: gives me a type mismatch when I replace that line with what you provided.

Comment: Just use copy and pastespecial then, not sure what that problem is atm.